# PHP - Storing text from fopen and fgets into a variable?

Tags: php

```
$ln = 0;
$start = 0;
$end = 3;  

$fd = fopen("output/test.txt", 'r'); // open the file

while(true) {
    $line = fgets($fd); // read next line
    if(!$line ||  $ln === $end + 1) {
        break;
    }
    if($ln >= $start && $ln <= $end) {
        echo $line;
    }
    $ln++;
}

fclose($fd); // close the file
```

Hello, I am trying to grab text off different lines and then turn them into a variable.

Text file:

```
1. One
2.
3.
4.
5. Two
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.

-----------------------------
```

But I am having a problem, I want to store the code into a variable to maybe put into a database in the future.

So I want to have each one to be a variable.

So I can then do:

```
echo $ONE
echo $TWO
```

I hope you understand me and can help me out.

**So to clarify, $ONE would echo line 1. and $TWO would echo line 2**

Comment: …and `$tenThousand` would contain line 10.000, right? How do you suppose to find those variables again? You don't know how many limes there are, thus you don't know how many variables there are. And you will need to tranlate the line number to a variable  name. That sounds like a ridiculous idea. Have you ever heard of arrays? In PHP those are perfectly well suited to store data.

Comment: @feeela I know how many lines there are!

Comment: you should definetally use an array for that

Comment: Use a numbered array. Seriously, there is no good reason to use individual named variables here.